# Android abd command

Tags: android, adb

I've an application,it has a data base.I've rooted my device.When i click data folder,it is empty.

I've three things to know,

**1.** What is the adb command to pull the data base file.

**2.** When i type this command adb devices,it showed emulator and my device number.What is that number,it is not IMEI number.

**3.** what is the services in the windows for adb?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: my answer to #1: `adb pull /data/data/[package name]/databases/[database name]`. i'm not sure if this will work for all devices (so I won't leave it as an answer) but it has always worked for me in the past.

Comment: Please ask this as 3 questions, not 1 combined one.  For the 3rd question, are you referring to Android Services, Microsoft Windows Services or something else - please clarify when you re-ask your questions.

Comment: @louielouie:yes,microsoft windwos services for adb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've rooted my device.When i click data folder,it is empty.

Don't use DDMS for this, use:

```
adb shell
su
cd /data
ls
```

You should see plenty in that folder.

1. Alex's suggestion in his comment has always worked for me as well: `adb pull /data/data/[package name]/databases/[database name]`
2. You're seeing the device ID. As you noticed, it is not the IMEI. Not all Android devices have IMEIs anyway. It's a separate identifier.
3. You'll have to clarify on this one, I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: **3** windows will have a services,i want to know what is the service that runs for adb

Comment: Not everything is a service. Some things are just executables. ADB does start up a daemon but I don't think it's a "Windows service". As for what it is... it's `adb.exe`. Not sure what else you're asking here. You can start it with `adb start-server` and you can stop it with `adb kill-server`.